# Java - Replacing String array to another String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace

I wanted to replace all the vowels from the words  Apple and Lenovo. Something like this as an output. `%20ppl%20, L%20n%20v%20` 
Here's my code

```
String[] dalek = new String[]{"Apple","Lenovo"};
String[] wy = new String[]{"a","e","i","o","u"};

for (int i = 0 ; i < dalek.length; i++ )
String wyx = wy[i];

dalek[i] = dalek[i].replace(wyx,"%20");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dalek));
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: you seem to be missing some parantheses in the for loop

Comment: What about a simpler `dalek[i] = dalek[i].replaceAll("[aeiou]","%20");`?

Comment: Just a side node: problems like this (and others like the double `break;` in iOS SSL code) are the reason why at our company we _always_ use curly braces, even for one-line statements.

Comment: @Thomas In this case it would help to just use indentation... but I also avoid omitting braces.

Comment: @Sulthan well, indentation might help, but [ask Apple](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) (ok, it wasn't a `break` but `goto`) ... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop has no curly brackets.

This means only `String wyx = wy[i];` will be executed in a loop, not the rest.

Here's a more elegant solution:

```
String[] dalek = new String[]{"Apple","Lenovo"};
String[] replaced = new String[dalek.length];
for (int i = 0; i < dalek.length; i++) {
    // assigning repalced[i] 
    //            | with dalek at index i
    //            |                      | case insensitive    
    //            |                      |   | vowels class (add "y" if necessary)
    //            |                      |   |         | with URL-encoded space
    replaced[i] = dalek[i].replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou]", "%20");
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(replaced));
```

**Output**

```
[%20ppl%20, L%20n%20v%20]
```

Comment: Not very elegant. The `dalek[i++]` should be declared as a separate variable. Otherwise it's just another dangeours sideeffect, hard to read. Also, when you need the iterator, then `for (int i; ...)` would be more elegant - declaring `i` in the outer scope is not pretty.

Comment: @Sulthan yep you caught me while I was editing already. I went with fast enumeration by habit, in this case a normal for loop is more suitable (see edit now).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String[] dalek = new String[]{"Apple","Lenovo"};
String[] wy = new String[]{"a","e","i","o","u"};

for (int i = 0 ; i < dalek.length; i++ ) {
   for (int j=0; j<wy.length;j++){
      String wyx = wy[j];
      dalek[i] = dalek[i].toLowerCase().replace(wyx,"%20");
   }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dalek));
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
String[] dalek = new String[] { "Apple", "Lenovo" };
String[] wy = new String[] { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u" };

for (int i = 0; i < dalek.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < wy.length; j++) {
        String wyx = wy[j];
        dalek[i] = dalek[i].replaceAll("(?i)[" + wyx + "]", "%20");
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dalek));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] dalek = new String[]{"Apple","Lenovo"};
    String[] wy = new String[]{"a","e","i","o","u"};

    for (int i = 0 ; i < dalek.length; i++ )
    {
        for(int j=0;j<wy.length;j++)
        {
            dalek[i] = dalek[i].replaceAll("(?i)"+wy[j], "%20");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dalek));
```

This works

Comment: It gives output as expected